# Angular 5 ReferenceError: require is not defined and TypeError: stream is undefined after implements a method to import JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am new to Angular(5) and I've tried to import a JSON document from my assets to a component.
This JSON document contains information for some selections in my form, I will present in this component.
But actually, after I implements this method:

```
private getJson(url: string, http: HttpClient) {
    if (!url.search("[^]*.json")) {
      throw InvalidPathException;
    } else {
      return http.get(url);
    }
}
```

and subscribe to this,
I get in my browser the Errors:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined
>
> TypeError: stream is undefined

Does anyone know this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: your error doesn't look like is coming from this code snippet.

Comment: Why are you passingHttpClient in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not recognized the error from the given code.. But I can share you another way to handle JSON document from your asset file in your angular5 code. You can change the below mentioned name and content of the JSON file according to your requirement. May be it will help you:

In the typescript file:

```
ngOnInit() {


this.http.get('assets/json/brandicon.json')
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json().icons)
  .then(brandIcon => this.brandIcon = brandIcon);}
```

And in the src\assets\json\brandicon.json

```
{
"icons": [
    {
        "icon": "fa fa-500px"
    },
    {
        "icon": "fa fa-amazon"
    }]}
```